# FreeMarker output being encoded to unicode when proceeded by question mark

Tags: freemarker

I'm parsing a JSON file with the following property

```
{
   "xml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
}
```

After I output the property it looks like this

`obj.xml?json_string`

```
{
  "xml": "\u003C?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
}
```

How can I stop FreeMarker from escaping/encoding the "<" character when followed by a question mark?

Comment: It's to protect from certain kind exploits, and is valid JSON. So most users shouldn't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with two solutions...

The first one is more manual:

```
<#assign obj ={"xml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"}>

${(obj.xml?json_string)?replace("\\u003C","<")}
```

The second one is more direct:

```
<#assign obj ={"xml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"}>

${obj.xml?j_string}
```

Both give the desired output `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>`